# I can't get $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaEmail() to work on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am running an ionic hybrid application. I have added  from    https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/README.md

I've run removed and added back the ios platform from my ionic project... and have seen

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" for ios
```

No matter what i do the result in teh code snippet below is false on iOS devices (emulators included). The iOS device doesn't seem to matter.

```
$cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaEmail(msg, sub, null, null, null, null).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
  // Success!
}, function(err) {
  // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
  console.log(err)
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know what more information i need to give to help as well.

Comment: What error does that give ?

Comment: No error. Just 'false' in console log.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on Simulators or Real Device.
This is will work on Real Device.If you are running Simulator or Your device don't have Twitter App will not share to twitter and return False.

Comment: Will it return false for shareViaEmail() if no twitter app, though?